# My segue or buttons doesn't work in swift

Tags: swift, function, button, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

My ideal scenario is that when I press the button called "1"/`ButtonArray.index[0]` it would execute a segue (The segue identifier is "segueFirst") to the another `UIViewController` called "FirstCollectionViewController".
But nothing happens when I press the button.

Now, I don't know if it has something to do with the segue, which I doubt. I do think it has something to do with the buttons but I can't figure it out.

PS: Inside the ButtonArray function (which is supposed to trigger the segue) I have tried `performSegueWithIdentifier` but nothing happens when I press the button.

I have also tried `presentViewController` but it gives me this error

> Cannot convert value of type "FirstCollectionViewController.Type" to expected argument type "UIViewController"

Which I don't understand because I have declared it a ViewController (In "The new VC").

VC1:

```
        import Foundation
        import UIKit

        class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

            var Array = [String]()
            var ButtonArray = [String]()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()

              Array =  ["1","2","3","4"]
              ButtonArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]


            }

            override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return Array.count
            }


            override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell


                let Label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

                Label.text = Array[indexPath.row]

                let Button = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton

                Button.setTitle(ButtonArray[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                Button.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonArray", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
                return cell

            }

            func ButtonArray(sender : UIButton) {
            print("Not the function")
                var selectedButtonCell = sender.superview as! UICollectionViewCell

                var indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(selectedButtonCell)
                if indexPath?.row == 0 {
print("Not the if-statement")
                   // presentViewController(FirstCollectionViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                   // performSegueWithIdentifier("segueFirst", sender: nil)
                }
            }
    }
```

**The new VC:**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
    class FirstCollectionViewController : UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
           print("hey")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add target with your button inside your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, Add this line after your `setTitle` method of `Button`

```
Button.addTarget(self,action: Selector("ButtonArray:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I think the problem is may be your button frame is too small so try to implement `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method of `UICollectionViewDelegate`, also set your collectionView delegate with your ViewController if it is not set, and check that it is calling `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` or not.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath")
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have tried what you requested but I got some errors like "Expected separator" so I changed it to "action: "ButtonArray"" instead of "action: #selector(ButtonArray(_:))".                                                                         But the thing is that it still won't trigger the action when I press it, I have placed 2 print statements to see if it is the button, the ButtonArray function or the if-statement which it is placed in and I found out that it is either the button or ButtonArray function, but i don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: Check my edit for `selector` syntax and for other detail.

Comment: When I commented out all lines of code inside my ''func ButtonArray'' except my print statements   (because I got a SIGABRT error  at the ''var selectedButtonCell = sender.superview as! UICollectionViewCell'', which I might make another question about later today)  and it printed the statements inside the ButtonArray function which means that the buttons are working! It did not print the "Inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath" but my main problem got solved thanks to you!